# in Smart pointer smart<int> o1 (new int() ) dont want to allow

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

In below program what happens on this line `smart<int> o1 = new int();`?

If i dont want to allow `smart<int> o1 (new int() );` then what should i do?

Can somebody help me out? I'd like to understand C++ better, I tried in multiple ways like overloading assignment operator, using explicit keyword as well.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class smart
{
    private:

     T *ptr;


    public:

    smart()
    {
        ptr = nullptr;
    }
     smart(T *ptr1)
    {
        cout<<"\nCalling Constructor *";
        ptr = ptr1;  
    }


     ~smart()
    {

        delete ptr; 
    }


    T *operator->()
    {
        cout<<"\nCalling ->";
        return ptr;
    }


    T &operator*()
    {
        cout<<"\nCalling *";
        return *ptr;
    }



};
int main()
{

    smart<int> o1 = new int() ; //What happen on this line
    smart<int> o1 (new int() ); //dont want to allow this syntax ?
    cout<<"\nHello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `smart o1 = new int();` uses your `smart(T *ptr1)` constructor, because you didn't make it `explicit`. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel by trying to build your own smart pointers? Just use `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` & `std::weak_ptr`. Smart pointers are *hard* to get right and the standard library already has perfectly good ones - use them.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: You cannot enable or disable syntax. But you can replace the default constructors with your own.